# Advanced Integration - WordPress + YOURLS

Tags: plugins, api, customization

I've been using a custom [YOURLS](http://yourls.org/) system to create my own URL shortener for my blog network for a while now.  Everything works just great with only a few exceptions (bugs already reported to the developer).

But I'm aiming for something a bit more complicated that's not included in the existing WordPress YOURLS plug-in.

### Currently

Right now, when a post is published, WordPress automatically logs in to YOURLS, creates a short URL, and pushes a notification to Twitter.  It works well and keeps track of everything for me (the short URL is memorized by WordPress and inserted into appropriate `<meta>` tags as well).

### What I want to do

I schedule my blog posts for 8am Pacific Time.  This works well *if* you're on Twitter at 8am.  But some people are browsing at lunch.  Some in the evening.

I want to schedule automated re-tweets of my short URL from within WordPress.  Some posts I want pushed out once ... others I want pushed out at 2 or 3 strategic times during the day.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably go about this way:
The plugin has a function called:

`wp_ozh_yourls_send_tweet($tweet);`

as you can see it accepts the tweet message and posts it to twitter,
also it has another function called:

`wp_ozh_yourls_geturl( $post_id );`

which accepts a post id and returns a shorturl as string.
so after knowing that I would use these two in conjunction with wordpress's

`wp_schedule_single_event`

and create my own function to use the plugins functions.

Now after that is said knowing how OZH codes his plugins i bet you can find hooks somewhere in there that will make you life a lot easier.

Hope this helps.